# Creating a head element isn't allowed in IE, and faulty in most browsers

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

Reading through [jsf.js](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.12/META-INF/resources/javax.faces/jsf-uncompressed.js?av=f) I see this :

```
// Creating a head element isn't allowed in IE, and faulty in most browsers,
// so it is not allowed
if (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "head") {
    throw new Error("Attempted to replace a head element - this is not allowed.");
}
```

I get that replacing the head tag isn't reliable but what about replacing its content ? What are the risks ?

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.innerHTML = "<title>lol magic</title>";
```